# How to compare 2 files in spark using scala with the same schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

So I have this 2 files (taking the hdfs file location of hive table) , file1 with history records and file2 with current day records. They both have the same schema. Now I want to do a CDC process to get the updated / newly inserted records after comparing the 2 files. 
There can be changes in multiple columns so we want to extract all the changed columns in a go.
Suppose the columns are:-  Customer_ID , Name, Address , Country.
Now Customer_ID is the primary key whereas the rest 3 columns may change.

File 1

```
12343| John| Rear exit market| SanFrancisco
45656| Bobs| Knewbound Road PD| Seattle
54345| Fersi| Dallas Road Pnth| Newyork
86575| Persa| Roman Building Path| Kirkland
64565| Camy| Olympus Ground 3rd| NewJersey
```

File 2

```
12343| John| World Centre Phase| SanFrancisco
54345| Posi| Dallas Road Pnth| Newyork
```

I want the final result to look like :-

```
12343|Rear exit market| World Centre Phase
54345| Fersi| Posi
```

So I want the primary key, previous records before change , new updated record which got updated in my final answer.

Comment: Can we see an example of your code?

Comment: I don't have one here and can't copy from my workstation in office as it's not allowed. Can you please advice how to move forward

Comment: Why is one record (12343) taking values from column 3, but the other taking values from column 2? Can you rekey what you have tried so far based on the data you have provided? So far it looks like a 3 liner (load two files into two datasets and join them) so shouldnt be too much typing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. As mentioned in my comment, it is pretty much a 3 or 4 liner, but I give a few alternatives.

```scala
// Load the data into 2 dataframes
val df1 = spark.read.option("sep","|").csv("file1a.txt")
val df2 = spark.read.option("sep","|").csv("file2a.txt")

// Next join the two dataframes using an INNER JOIN on the key as follows:
val joined = df1.joinWith(df2, df1.col("_c0") === df2.col("_c0"))
```

There is no header information in the file, so the columns will get default names. The schema of joined is basically a Tuple2 with each Tuple2 containing the list of columns from each side of the join.

Here are the schemas:

```scala
scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)


scala> joined.printSchema
root
 |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
```

The last step is (I think) an extrapolation of what you want to produce. I think you want to show which columns have different values. The output format you show has, IMHO, a couple of potential problems. I think you are just wanting to show in the two output columns a value that is different. IMHO, this has a couple of challenges:

1. What if there are two columns in a record that have different values - and thus you need to display 4 (or more) values for each output record?
2. What if there are lots of records with differences, it will make it very difficult to find the original columns that were different (since any identification of the column with the difference is lost in the output) - this will be more difficult with records with large numbers of columns.
3. The solution will likely be more complicated as you shuffle the columns around in the result set.

The following output format addresses the above by showing all of the columns along with an indicator to show which columns have differing values. The indicator is the key as it makes the differences easier to spot.
Here is the "brute force" method where every column is listed and every difference determined manually.

```scala
joined.select($"_1._C0".as("id"), $"_1._c1", $"_2._c1", when(col("_1._c1") === col("_2._c1"), "").otherwise("ne").as("c1 Ind"),
  $"_1._c2", $"_2._c2", when(col("_1._c2") === col("_2._c2"), "").otherwise("ne").as("c2 Ind"),
  $"_1._c3", $"_2._c3", when(col("_1._c3") === col("_2._c3"), "").otherwise("ne").as("c3 Ind")).show(false)
```

Which produces:

```
+-----+-----+----+------+----------------+------------------+------+------------+------------+------+
|id   |_c1  |_c1 |c1 Ind|_c2             |_c2               |c2 Ind|_c3         |_c3         |c3 Ind|
+-----+-----+----+------+----------------+------------------+------+------------+------------+------+
|12343|John |John|      |Rear exit market|World Centre Phase|ne    |SanFrancisco|SanFrancisco|      |
|54345|Fersi|Posi|ne    |Dallas Road Pnth|Dallas Road Pnth  |      |Newyork     |Newyork     |      |
+-----+-----+----+------+----------------+------------------+------+------------+------------+------+
```

The brute force method is tedious and difficult to enter - especially for larger result sets. So we can use some Scala magic to make this a bit more elegant.

```scala
// Define a helper function that takes a column name and returns the three parts needed
// to generate the output for that column. i.e. select the column from the two sides of the joined result set
// and generate the case statement to generate the "ne" indicator if the two values
// are unequal.
def genComp(colName:String) = List(s"_1.$colName", s"_2.$colName", s"case when _1.$colName = _2.$colName then '' else 'ne' end as ${colName}_ind")

// Run the query to produce the results:
joined.selectExpr(
    (List("_1._C0 as id") ++ genComp("_c1") ++ genComp("_c2") ++ genComp("_c3")) : _*
  ).show(false)
```

When run, this produces the same result as the "brute force" method.

How does this work? Well the magic is in the second line and a feature of the selectExpr method.

The selectExpr method has the following signature: `def selectExpr(exprs: String*): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`. This means it can accept a variable number of string arguments.

To generate the arguments passed to selectExpr, I use this construct `List (strings) : _*`. This is Scala "magic" that takes a List of strings and converts it to a Variable number of arguments parameter list.

The rest is pretty straightforward. Basically the genComp function returns a List of strings which identify the column in each side of the joined DataFrame along with the inequality indicator generation logic. Concatenates them all together. The result is converted to the parameter list passed to selectExpr which ultimately runs the same query as the "brute force" method.

Here is an interesting thought that I will leave for you as an exercise: use the schema of df1 to generate the list of columns to output using genComp (as opposed to simply manually concatenating them as I've shown).

Here is a *big* hint:

```scala
val cols = df1.schema.filter(c => c.name != "_c0").map(c => List(c.name)).flatten
cols.foreach(println)
```

Comment: If this has helped you with your problem, could you please accept it by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the answer. If it hasn't helped you feel free to add on to the original question.